# Minitest assert_equal failing when should be equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, floating-point, rounding, minitest, floating-point-comparison

I have a minitest test that is asserting if a decimal is the same.  Wondering why this

My assert code:

```
assert_equal -9.04, elts[2].change.round(2)
```

Failure:

> Failure: LeaveTypePolicyTest#test_case_12
> [/usr/src/app/test/models/leave_type_policy_test.rb:1007]
> Minitest::Assertion: Expected: -9.04   Actual: -0.904e1

Anyone experienced this? and perhaps why its failing? I have many many tests doing similar assertions, but only this for some reason fails.

Comment: What datatype/class is `change`?

Comment: @Eyeslandic,  it is a decimal in my database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `assert_in_delta`, for example:

```
assert_in_delta -9.04, elts[2].change, 0.01
```

SEE ALSO: Test::Unit::Assertions#assert_in_delta: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/test-unit/test-unit/Test%2FUnit%2FAssertions:assert_in_delta

For example, this passes:

```
assert_in_delta 0.33, 1.0/3, 0.01
```

---

It is possible that the initial test failure was caused by comparing `float` to `BigDecimal` or something similar to that. Apparently, Ruby needs the classes in such a comparison to match. Here is a simple example that reproduces a similar behavior:

```
bar = -9.04                       # Float
baz = BigDecimal.new("-0.904e1")  # BigDecimal (not Float)

puts bar == baz                   # false
puts bar == baz.round(2)          # false (even after rounding!)
puts bar == baz.to_f              # true (converted to Float)
puts bar == baz.to_f.round(2)     # true (same, plus rounded)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks.  However still confused on the behaviour into why it fails especially with round().